# ECMAScript Associative Array via Object w/ prototype null?

Tags: javascript, ecma262, ecmascript-5

I see a lot of people doing this

```
Object.prototype.foo = 'HALLO';
var hash = {baz: 'quuz'};

for ( var v in hash ) {
  // Do not print property `foo`
  if ( hash.hasOwnProperty(v) ) {
    console.log( v + " is a hash property" );
  }
}
```

My question is rather than testing `.hasOwnProperty` each time you wish to use an `Object` as a hash why not just set the `.__proto__` to `null` on the object? †

```
hash.prototype = null;
hash.__proto__ = null;

for ( var v in hash ) {
  // Do not print property `foo`
  console.log( v + " is a hash property" );
}
```

It has been brought to my attention that `__proto__` is nonstandard. That still doesn't answer the question though...

var foo = Object.create(null);
  Object.getPrototypeOf(foo);

This can't be an original question, but I can't find *anything* about changing `__proto__` to `null` to eliminate the drawbacks of having to check for inheritance? What's wrong with this approach, seems to make code faster (don't have to check properties of `Object`) and cleaner?

† And the `.prototype` property if you plan on making future children of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's **nothing inherently wrong** with creating [[Prototype]]'less objects to avoid `hasOwnProperty`-based checks during "hash" enumeration.

In fact, some of the libraries I know (fuse.js being one of them, IIRC) do exactly that.

Now on to the practical problems:

1. __proto__ is **non-standard**. See my [compat. table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/non-standard/). Notice how IE doesn't support __proto__ up until and including IE9. Of course, IE9 supports `Object.create` and so it becomes possible to create [[Prototype]]'less object with `Object.create(null)` but that still leaves IE6, IE7 and IE8. Oh and Opera <10.10, as you can see (which doesn't support `Object.create`). Fortunately, existence (and functionality) of __proto__ can be easily feature tested, which is why non-supporting browsers can be made to take `hasOwnProperty`-based or some other route.
2. Removing [[Prototype]] from the object "removes" all of the `Object.prototype.*` methods. Naturally. So, for example, `myHash.toString()` (or even `myHash + ''`) will now error out unless you give that hash `toString` method. Ditto for `valueOf`, `hasOwnProperty`, and all the other `Object.prototype.*` methods. This isn't big deal, of course, as you can always define those methods (and probably *should* — to make them specialized for hash usage) but it's more work nevertheless.

As far not finding anything about this approach... I was talking about it at least 2 years ago :) — http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/msg/9451c45080b5e9f0 (likely earlier too, but can't find any other posts on comp.lang.javascript at the moment). There are more interesting findings about browsers' behavior with __proto__ === null in that thread. Check it out.

Comment: Like I said, I was hesitant to say I thought of it first. Just that I couldn't find anyone else discussing it.

Answer (score 0):

Not all JS implementations have `__proto__` as it is non-standard feature.

Comment: Is there a standard way to change the prototype of an object in ECMA5?

Comment: I'm not sure this answer the question either way, what about the empty-function trick... The basic question is, why doesn't anyone get rid of inheritance rather than testing for it at every point of usage?  I can't be the first person to come upon this idea.

Comment: Rather, this trick: `var foo = Object.create(null, {name: { value: "hello", enumerable: true } }); Object.getPrototypeOf(foo);` Now the prototype is null... What would be the downside of doing this? Now you don't have to test for `hasOwnProperty`